# How can I tell Outlook to use an existing PST-file in its first start?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pst

In an automated installation of MS-Office I try to make Outlook use an existing PST-file on its first start via MSP configuration but Outlook ignores the file and creates a new file with a counter "(2)". How can I tell Outlook to use an existing file in its first start?

**what I've tried:**

1. Office 10 is installed but Outlook not yet started for the first time
2. create an MSP-file (via `setup /Admin`) which configures an acccount in a profile "profilename" and has the name "username@domain.com"
3. run `msiexec /p myconfig.msp`
4. copy the file `username@domain.com - profilename.pst` to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook\username@domain.com - profilename.pst`
5. start Outlook
6. Outlook creates a new file `username@domain.com - profilename(2).pst` and ignores my file `username@domain.com - profilename.pst`

If `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook` is empty, i.e. the file doesn't exist, Outlook creates the file without counter: `username@domain.com - profilename.pst`. The configuration of the MSP-file ist working properly but Outlook ignores the existing file.

**Update**

This problem occurs with IMAP-accounts. It seems that Outlook handles pst differently, depending whether they correspont to an POP or an IMAP account.

Answer (score -1):

You could open outlook first (with no PST), close it, then copy the old PST file on top of the newly created one.

Comment: this way outlook creates a new pst as I've described. Did you test what you describe? Did it work for you?